# Rails rake task incredible slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I wrote a rake task in rails to update my user database with a `gender` value. All it should do is loop through my users and update the gender attribute with a value that I get from a "gender detection" gem (which works well).

The rake task runs for minutes now although I only have a few dozens of records in my database:

```
require 'gender_detector'

namespace :user do
  desc 'Assign gender to all users'
  task :genderize => :environment do

    User.all.each do |user|
      gd = GenderDetector.new(:case_sensitive => false)
      gender = gd.get_gender(user.firstname)

      sql = "UPDATE users SET gender = '#{gender}' WHERE id = #{user.id}"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
    end

  end
end
```

what do I do wrong?

Comment: Try adding some debug values. At the simplest level add a `puts " line #{i = ( i||0 + 1)}"` after each line and see which one takes the longest to print. The line before is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several components in that rake tasks: rails boot, database, genderdetector, etc. You should isolate and benchmark each component to understand what is the bottleneck.

Depending on how many gems you have, the Rails environment may take from a few seconds up to a minute to book. Therefore, the `:environment` requirement may slow down your task.

I have no idea what the `GenderDetector` does and how it works internally. If it queries a web service, for example, IO may slow down your task as well.

Finally, you can optimize your query as well to avoid loading unnecessary data from the database.

```
require 'gender_detector'

namespace :user do
  desc 'Assign gender to all users'
  task :genderize => :environment do

    User.select('id, firstname').each do |user|
      gd = GenderDetector.new(:case_sensitive => false)
      gender = gd.get_gender(user.firstname)

      User.update_all({ gender: gender }, user_id: user.id)
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: I agree; you need to identify which is the part of that that is slow. (Not sure the update_all is right though - could just do `user.update_attributes(gender: gender)`, or `update_column`).

Comment: thanks. Figured out that putting ``gd = GenderDetector.new(:case_sensitive => false)``out of the loop solved the problem!

Answer (score -1):

Because for updating every user you use separate query to your DB.

Comment: A few dozen DB queries shouldn't take minutes